# Как виртуальные машины работают с драйверами USB устройств?

Tags: linux, usb, mac, виртуальная-машина

Я разрабатываю приложение на Java под windows, которое работает с составным USB   устройством. Устройство имеет 6 интерфейсов, к двум из которых мне необходимо получать доступ. Первый это HID интерфейс и windows позволяет работать с ним сразу, без установки сторонних драйверов. Второй хто bulk  интерфйс, и для работы с ним под  windows я заменяю оригинальный драйвер этого интерфейса устройства на универсальный USB  драйвер WinUSB.

Я бы хотел выпустить своё приложение так же для Linux и возможно Mac, но у меня совсем нет опыта разработки под эти ОС.

Мой вопрос в следующем - будет ли виртуальная Linux машина работать с моим USB устройством точно также, как если бы это была не виртуальная машина? Имеют ли значение драйверы   для этого устройства, установлены в windows в которой я запускаю виртуальную машину?

И возможно ли тоже самое с виртуальным Mac ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке***. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Написал по русски, извиняюсь.

Comment: я думаю, что попробовать будет быстрее, чем тут ответят. Скорее всего под линукосом заработает через виртуалку. Правда наверно нужно будет настроить проброс устройства.